# How can i ignore a space in file name using if condition

Tags: shell-script

I tried:

```
for item in *
do 
if [ -d  ${item} ]
then 
echo "$item" 
fi
done
```

and when a file name with space is read it prints error:

```
 line 11: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: I tried using IFS and sed but failed

Comment: I want to learn to filter whitespaces in IF condition and a solution using IFS or sed will be great THANX for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Quote the expansion of `$item`, just like you're already doing with `echo`:

```
for item in *; do
    if [ -d "$item" ]; then
        echo "$item"
    fi
done
```

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)

Note also that adding a `/` to the end of the pattern will force matching of subdirectories (if *anything* matches).